# How to clone my VirtualBox guest Ubuntu on Mac host to a bootable USB?

Tags: linux, virtualbox, clone, bootable-media

I have a guest Ubuntu running as a VM via VirtualBox on my host Mac. I'd like to "clone" this Ubuntu to a USB, as a backup, and be able to boot either as a VM or even my Mac eventually.

Think of Carbon Clone Copy does for Mac. The closest app I found similar to CCC for linux was Clonezilla, but the solutions I saw didn't address my scenario (running VirtualBox on Mac).

Since my Ubuntu is only 12GB and my USB3 drive is 64GB, it would even better if I could partition my USB drive to use the remaining space.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can make a full clone directly in Virtual Box. There are plenty guides how to do this. I hope my answer suits your needs. You do not have to minus the answer. This is obvious that first what you have to do is to ask Google in English how to perform a full clone in Virtual Box. Then moving the clone to usb stick is a piece of cake. I am not giving answers on a golden plate by default. Sorry. This way you will not learn how to make it work.

Comment: I know about the VB clone stuff, I use it for debugging, but I will check how to "copy" this clone to a usb.

Comment: Check this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2tUkmeDdXjM

Comment: This `systemback` is the answer and with `balenaEtcher.app`, it's just perfect.

Comment: I did not know than balena etcher can do that. I usually use it to make bootable usb sticks with many Linux distros.

Answer (score 0):

I found another solution that's more convenient in my case. The problem with `systemback` is that it'll will create `iso` which is `readonly`, hence not good solution if I want to work on it.

In the end, I found this:

```
VBoxManage clonemedium --format RAW _source_.vdi _image_.img
```

Then I used [balenaEtcher](https://www.balena.io/etcher/).